# Extract unique constraint fields from sql exception

Tags: c#

Is there any way to extract field names comming from sql exception? In the first example i get `Geto` in the second: `Rest, 1`

**Example 1:**

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__T_Client_NameSector'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_Clients'. 
The duplicate key value is (Geto).
The statement has been terminated.
```

**Example 2:**

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__T_Client_NameSector'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_Clients'. 
The duplicate key value is (Rest, 1).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: The error means that you're trying to insert a key value  that already exists in the database. Check your request or `insert query` or include your `INSERT STATEMENT` here

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I know what does error mean, i catch it and want to read field name/names out of it.

Comment: Share your statement so let it be solved.

Comment: do you wish to parse the Exception ex ' s ex.StackTrace? That a really hard mission. Are you sure?

Comment: @LongChalk there is always statment like: The duplicate key value is () .. Inside bracekts are fields i need to extract. I

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like

```
catch (SqlException ex1) {
int start_index = ex1.StackTrace.IndexOf("The duplicate key value is (");
if (start_index > 1) {
in end_index = ex1.StackTrace.SubString(start_index).IndexOf(")");
string[] myVariableName = ex1.SubString(start_index, end_index).split(',');
.... use as best you see fit ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query below (from the [site](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-all-table-constraints)) to get all the constraints in your database.  If you need to consume this in your application, you can create a stored proc or a view and call it in your catch block.  I hope this helps.

```
select table_view,
object_type, 
constraint_type,
constraint_name,
details
from (
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
        case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
            when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
            end as [object_type],
        case when c.[type] = 'PK' then 'Primary key'
            when c.[type] = 'UQ' then 'Unique constraint'
            when i.[type] = 1 then 'Unique clustered index'
            when i.type = 2 then 'Unique index'
            end as constraint_type, 
        isnull(c.[name], i.[name]) as constraint_name,
        substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [details]
    from sys.objects t
        left outer join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
        left outer join sys.key_constraints c
            on i.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
            and i.index_id = c.unique_index_id
       cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                        from sys.index_columns ic
                            inner join sys.columns col
                                on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                            and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                                order by col.column_id
                                for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    where is_unique = 1
    and t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    union all 
    select schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
        'Table',
        'Foreign key',
        fk.name as fk_constraint_name,
        schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name
    from sys.foreign_keys fk
        inner join sys.tables fk_tab
            on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        inner join sys.tables pk_tab
            on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols
            on fk_cols.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Check constraint',
        con.[name] as constraint_name,
        con.[definition]
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Default constraint',
        con.[name],
        col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition]
    from sys.default_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id) a
order by table_view, constraint_type, constraint_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to assume the precise error message format (which is sensible), but you maintain a convention for your unique constraint names, you can leverage that. Split the error string into words, using MSSQL identifier rules, and see if there is one that starts with "UQ_". Like this:

```
catch(SqlException exc)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)");
    MatchCollection ma = rx.Matches(exc.Message);
    string ConstraintName = ma.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value.StartsWith("UQ_"));
}
```

If you are interested in other constraint types, leverage their naming conventions too.

This assumes the built-in format strings of MSSSQL won't contain words starting with UQ_. Seems unlikely to me.